# Temporary vote timestamp locking

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

It might be a good idea to have a system in place that would temporally lock the timestamp of a vote in place for situations where it is later retracted and redone (with the exact same vote direction) in order for the vote to have a reputation impact.

I would suggest a 5 minute grace period where if a user retracts a vote and during that 5 minute period if they vote again in the same direction the timestamp of the original vote is used for reputation impact.

Example:

User votes on a post but no reputation impact is observed (impacted user is either at 1 rep or at rep cap for the day). Later the user undoes the vote and reapplies the vote in the same direction causing a reputation impact for the user they voted on.

Comment: .......... Why?

Comment: You mean you can't undownvote, re-read the edited post, decide it's still not a good question, and redownvote?  It's a contrived scenario, but I don't think the proposal is fully thought through.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Why? What I mean is if you downvote a question from a new user with 1 rep, someone comes by and upvotes it, you reverse your vote and downvote again causing that person to lose 2 rep when your original downvote caused them to lose none. On the flip side you upvote a question and note that they got no rep because of the rep cap and later come back and after someone else edits it or you do redo the vote so that they get the rep from the upvote. While I do admit this doesn't happen often I don't see why this type of gaming the reputation system can't be fixed.

Comment: @fbueckert No I mean undoing and redoing a vote to cause a reputation change when it did not happen on the original vote.

Comment: Yeah; you're basing it on the fact that you believe it's an abuse, when there is at least one scenario where it's using the system for it's intended purpose.

Comment: @fbueckert How is it note abuse? At that point you are no longer voting on the post but on the user themselves as the vote done not only to signify a bad post but to also cost the user reputation. If all you where doing is signalling bad content there would be no reason at all to redo the vote to counter the reputation gained from the upvote.

Comment: Easy: User sees bad post.  Downvotes, moves on.  A day or two later, the poster has edited it.  User sees the edit, undownvotes, and proceeds to read the post.  Decides it still does not meet the quality standard, and redownvotes.  You're telling me that's an abuse?

Comment: @fbueckert I would ask why someone would retract a downvote based on an edit they have not yet read. Also in that case the downvote would still end up with the exact same reputation impact on the poster.

Comment: I'm using a contrived scenario to show where this proposal fails.  It's *extremely* hard to judge intent, and it's going to be extremely hard to detect when this is user targeted, instead of on the post.

Comment: This feature request fixes a loophole, without actually fixing it. The downvoter would simply need to wait a few minutes before recasting the vote. This problem can't really be solved without removing the ability to change votes altogether. The 2-3 people who are doing this network wide will simply wait 5 minutes.

Comment: @KevinB So do nothing to fix a loophole that lets people game the reputation system? 5 minutes was just a suggestion that could be tuned. Personally I think it is a bit silly that a no reputation impact vote can be easily turned into a reputation impact vote.

Comment: I find it silly to be upset that someone who got away with *not* losing reputation by receiving a downvote was then able to receive the downvote penalty later. Is it petty? sure... but who cares?

Comment: @fbueckert I fail to see how not changing the recorded timestamp of a vote because it was undone and redone again in a short period of time is judging intent rather then just not changing the overall status of that vote. What I am suggesting would leave the posts vote count exactly the same as it was before the vote was undone and redone.

Comment: The vote count is the same *regardless*.  This feature request is specifically attempting to target intent, not vote count.

Comment: @KevinB But does it make sense for that to happen? Seems to go around the idea of not getting negative reputation to be able to change a vote to cause reputation lose at a later date when it did not do so initially

Comment: @fbueckert No it is meant to target reputation changes from toggling a vote regardless of the intent behind it. I see the point others have about it not being a great fix but I find it strange that you are fixated on intent.

Comment: ...Because the only reason anyone would do this would be to cause reputation changes.  That's why they do this.  Hence, intent.  Intent is an incredibly hard thing to determine.

Comment: @fbueckert so you are saying the only reason you would do this would be to get around the system to prevent reputation lose/gain in certain situations? Sounds to me like you basically removed the need to determine intent.

Comment: No, that's what *you're* saying.  I've been pointing out that there are valid reasons for these actions, and you're going to have an *extremely* hard time proving any specific scenario is for bad faith.

Comment: @fbueckert And I have been pointing out that the reason doesn't matter in the end just the fact that it circumvents part of the reputation system and I suggested removing the ability to circumvent it in that method

Comment: If the reason doesn't matter, this feature request is moot; the vote count is the same *regardless* of the order of operations it comes in.  A good faith reevaluation of a post *does* matter; we wouldn't allow people to remove their votes if it didn't.  A simpler request would be to just lock in votes the instant they are cast; no need for all this wait time and judging of intent for an extremely small corner case.

Comment: @fbueckert again this isn't about the vote count but the reputation impact and I would question the purpose of undoing a vote and redoing it again quickly in the first place as reevaluation of a post. If you are going to reevaluate a post you should make your decision before you change your vote and recast it. And in fact they don't let you remove your vote after 5 minutes unless it has been edited and changed.

Comment: when i downvote a new user's post because it's unclear and/or low quality, and it then receives an upvote, there's literally nothing i can do to bring the user's rep to where I believe it belongs: 1. changing it from 6 to 4 isn't all that much of a victory. The OP isn't who I want to penalize at that point anyway, it's the user abusing upvotes.

Comment: Yeah, you can't change your vote.  But why is your way of judging posts the only way to do it?  Why can't someone come back to a post they downvoted, wonder why they did so, undo it, re-read the post, go, "Oh, right, that's why", and redownvote?  Why is that everyone has to follow your specific process?

Comment: @fbueckert and my suggestion would have no impact on how that works to the user doing that, it would just prevent that vote cycle from impacting reputation if it did not do so the last time it was cast

Comment: And why is that so important?  You've given no justification as to why that is worth doing.

Comment: And one very real scenario that happens depressingly often: New user posts question.  It's crap.  It gets downvoted.  Someone makes the effort to edit it, so it's no longer crap.  It gets a few upvotes, and undownvotes.  New user rolls back the edit, because they don't understand, and now it gets more downvotes again.  You're telling me those votes should have their rep changes discarded because they were cast with, by your view, intent to remove reputation?

Comment: @fbueckert if all that happens within a span of 5 minutes? Sure

Comment: I would vehemently disagree.  Good faith trumps potential abuse, in my opinion.

Comment: **Related for context:** [Redoing downvote to counter upvote on new user -- Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382910/2821954)

Answer (score 8):

I honestly doubt people are doing this; first of all, their original vote is likely to be locked in already. They can only retract it if the post has been edited after they voted. Second, it's not obvious to see if a user rep capped (unless it's an answer posted on the current UTC day with a score of 20 or more). Finally, if a user is still determined to make their vote count, they'll check the reputation of their victim, see that it fails to change, so after the first time they'll probably guess what's going on, and next time they'll just wait another five minutes before recasting the vote. Wait ... they probably even retract their vote *again*, and eventually they'll succeed in their mission on the first post where they try this.

Comment: But it is easy to see when you are voting on a new users post and you see an upvote come in shortly after you downvote.

Comment: @JoeW it sounds like you are stalking users, who post things you don't like.From the comments under your question, it sounds like your goal it ensure that your down vote cause the most harm to new users as possible. Have you read the [Code of Conduct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: @JamesJenkins Where did I ever say I was doing this. I am making this suggestion to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @JoeW: There is no point spending time to prevent something from happening unless it's something that is actually *happening* to any significant degree. Time is best spent solving actual problems, not hypothetical ones.